# Migrating CRA to Webpack 5

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-5

I'm trying to migrate an ejected create-react-app to Webpack 5 and running into this error:

```
Failed to compile.

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I think the error is coming from `output.path` which by default from CRA is undefined in development, I have tried to set it to an empty string - or an absolute path and it would not resolve. I have been able to successfuly get Webpack 5 working on a non-cra app with leaving the path as undefined, so I'm thinking its related to the CRA config. Also I have followed this guide with no success https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-buck-shu04

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing with same problem. This error is raised from `webpack-manifest-plugin`. **Webpack 5** is not supported at now, but maintainer [are planning](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin/issues/222) to add support.
So you can change several lines in `default.config.js` `output` section from:

```js
 output: {
   // The build folder.
   path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
   // blah blah blah
 }
```

to:

```js
 output: {
   // The build folder.
   path: paths.appBuild,
   // blah blah blah
 }
```

Error `The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined` disappears. But it still not working for me. I get endless loading in browser. I should to debug it more careful and update answer later.
So, I tried to remove `webpack-manifest-plugin` from my configuration, but it still not working.

Comment: Thanks, that link is helpful to monitor the status

Comment: hi EvgeniyRRU, even  I am getting endless loading in browser

how did you resolved

Comment: Well, I just dropped CRA in favor of my own Webpack config.

Comment: @SathvikNasani, I've used the below branch which has all the WP5 related updates and fixed few bugs here and there and voila I am able to run the app in WP5 with CRA: https://github.com/raix/create-react-app/tree/webpack5-update

Comment: @KumarLachhani, could you pls share what fixes you made on PR branch with webpack 5. I'm able to start it but also stuck with endless loading in the browser and 'starting development server' in the terminal.

Comment: @A1exandr, Pls follow the below steps:
1) Take checkout of: https://github.com/raix/create-react-app/tree/webpack5-update
2) Eject your CRA App
3) Update webpack and it's dependencies. Follow: https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/
4) Compare package.json from yours and webpack5-update branch and do npm install to install the remaining libs.
5) Replace the webpack.config.js from the above webpack5-update branch and replace in your CRA app.
6) Fix the few known bugs in react-dev-utils in node_modules (till the fix comes officially) - Let me know if you need help in fixing, you can google too.

Comment: @KumarLachhani how do we generate create-react-app from its repo file. I didn't seem to find a way to generate the app and ejecting it. is it from the react-scripts folder or what? can you help? using npx and ejecting the app will be still using webpack 4.44.2. Idk why

Comment: @FadilNatakusumah, you must have your own CRA App on which you would want to apply WP 5 and use module federation. If yes then you can follow the above mentioned steps. Let me know in case of any difficulties / queries / concerns.. Moreover, after ejection, you will still be on Webpack 4. You need to upgrade to WP 5 as a part of Step 3 mentioned in the above steps (refer above comment)